# iPhone: how to keep integer value on UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am working on Twitter on iPhone

now i have to keep the count of Friend, Tweets, Followers etc on UILabel

how to work with this

```
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {

        NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);   // userInfo contains all user details like userName, screenName, count of Friends, Followers, Following, Status Count etc 

    NSLog(@"User Info Received: %d", [userInfo count]); 


    NSMutableDictionary *profileData = [userInfo objectAtIndex:0]; //converting userInfo array into profileData dictionary

    lblUserName.text = [profileData objectForKey:@"name"]; // lblUserName is UILabel, userName keeping on Label

       lblLocation.text = [profileData objectForKey:@"location"]; // lblLocation is UILabel, Location keeping on Label

    lblDescription.text = [profileData objectForKey:@"description"]; // lblDescription is UILabel, Location keeping on Label

/////*** Up to here all working but how to Keep integer value on UILabel *****/////

          lblFolCount = (NSNumber *)[profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"]; //how to keep user Followers Count on UILable 

    lblFavCount = (NSNumber *)[profileData objectForKey:@"favourites_count"]; //how to keep user Followers Count on UILable 

    lblStatusCount = (NSNumber *) [profileData objectForKey:@"statuses_count"]; //how to keep user statuses count on UILable 

    lblFriends = (NSNumber *) [profileData objectForKey:@"friends_count"]; //how to keep user friends count on UILable 

}

////*****This info Display on debugger console****///////
////NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);   // by this we get info on debugger console
```

User Info Received: (
        {

```
    "created_at" = "Tue Nov 02 14:42:42 +0000 2010";

    description = "being honest";

    favorited = false;

    "favourites_count" = 0;

     "followers_count" = 5;

    "friends_count" = 21;

    "listed_count" = 0;

    location = Chennai;

    name = "nanda kishore reddyv";

       "profile_background_color" = EDECE9;

    "profile_background_image_url" = "http://a2.twimg.com/a/1292975674/images/themes/theme3/bg.gif";

    "profile_background_tile" = false;

    "profile_image_url" = "http://a2.twimg.com/a/1292975674/images/default_profile_6_normal.png";

    "retweet_count" = 0;

    "screen_name" = velugotinanda;

    source = "<a href=\"http://www.icodeblog.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">iCodeBlog Oauth Demo</a>";

    status = "Mon Dec 27 09:22:44 +0000 2010";
    "statuses_count" = 15;

    "time_zone" = "Indiana (East)";

   verified = false;
}
```

)
2011-01-01 10:38:29.460 IdeaTweet[471:207] User Info Received: 1

Thanks YOU can you tell me 
how to Keep integer Value on UILabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lblFolCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
                     [[profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"] intValue]];
```

Here,

```
UILabel *lblFolCount;
NSMutableDictionary *profileData;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have it like this.

```
lblFolCount = (NSNumber *) [profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"];
[lblFolc setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [lblFolCount intValue]]];
```

Comment: hi Simon Thanks,my UILabel is lblFolcount, and can you Tell me, what is int lblFolCount and Followers_lblFolCount in your method Please

Comment: hi simon i am getting 1 error and 2 warnings with this,can you explain me we bit detail what you used in the method like int lblFolCount , lblFolc, followers_lblFolCount means please

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Replace followers_lblFolCount with lblFolCount.  I've edited the code, check if this works now.

Comment: local declaration of 'lblFolCount' hides instance variable- warning   invalid receiver type 'int' and ERROR- Followers_Count Undeclared(first use in this function)

Comment: You are getting the error "local declaration of 'lblFolCount' hides instance variable" because you may have declared the variable 'lblFolCount' in your interface file, and again you declare it in the line "int lblFolCount = [[profileData objectForKey:@"followers_count"] intValue];
". So remove the *int* from that line. I guess 'lblFolCount' is NSNumber. I've edited my answer. Check it now.